# How do i know when training with lightning with ddp strategy (with multi gpu single node) what gpu was assigned to the current process?

Tags: pytorch-lightning

I have two gpus on my machine and would like to behave a little differently in the dataloader depending on the gpu the thread/process is running on. How do I know the GPU/name? There is global_rank in distrinuted.py but i don't think it is accesible to the dataloader.

The trainer is running with strategy "ddp"

Answer (score 0):

There are two environment variables, LOCAL_RANK and NODE_RANK that holds a unique id per ddp process (0, 1, 2). It seems like the GPUS are allocated based on their id to the process.
The environment variables are not defined yet when the datamodule is initialised, only when it is called.